# Object lost after include in function

Tags: php

I create a new object `$Manager` in my index.php(`$Manager = new Manager()`). After that I do some routing etc. to eventually end up in a controller. That controller includes the view of choice.

Now; I'd like to use `$Manager` in that view, without having to assign a `global $Manager` in the method that includes it.

My controller looks like this:(stripped all the other methods)

```
<?php
Class PostController extends Controller {
    public function home () {
        $items = $this->getItems();
        require_once(ROOT . 'application/items/post/home.view.php');
    }
}
?>
```

In that home.view.php file I include view.view.php in a loop and do:

```
<?= $Manager->currentPageItem(); ?>
```

but it gives the error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: Manager in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\blurp\application\items\post\view.view.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

I've tried making `$Manager` a global in the index.php, to no avail. adding `global $Manager` to the `home` method works; but is not my solution of choice(Since every method would need that than)

How can I get includes from functions to keep using global variables like my `$Manager`?

Comment: By the way globals are not good idea. It's only beginning of your frustration.

Comment: @estshy I dont necessarily want to use global-globals. I still want just one manager to be created in my index.php file(Which gets loaded every time) which I can use throughout all the files to come. Justinas as mentioned in my intro; it's in the index.php.

Comment: So why don't you pass this object to controller class which could extend some "base class" that would keep reference to this object?

Comment: @estshy that feels kinda hacky. Is that how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using globals use dependency injection

```
//Your controller
class PostController extends Controller {
    public function home() {
        $items = $this->getItems();
        require_once(ROOT . 'application/items/post/home.view.php');
    }
}

//Somewhere in low end part of code
class Controller extends BaseClass {

}

abstract class BaseClass {

    public $manager;

    /**
     * Passing dependencies
     */
    public function init(Manager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
}


//Index, router, whatever
$controller = new PostController;
$controller->init(new Manager);
$controller->home();

//View
echo $this->manager->currentPageItem();
```